# How to number lines read from a file using conduits?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I'm a Haskell beginner trying to wrap my head around the conduit library.

I've tried something like this, but it does not compile:

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

numberLine :: Monad m => Conduit BS.ByteString m BS.ByteString
numberLine = conduitState 0 push close
  where
    push lno input = return $ StateProducing (lno + 1) [BS.pack (show lno ++ BS.unpack input)]
    close state = return state

main = do
  runResourceT $ CB.sourceFile "wp.txt" $= CB.lines $= numberLine $$ CB.sinkFile "test.txt"
```

It seems that the state in conduitState must be of the same type as the conduit's input type. Or at least that's what I understand from the error message:

```
$ ghc --make exp.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( exp.hs, exp.o )

exp.hs:8:27:
    Could not deduce (Num [ByteString]) arising from the literal `0'
    from the context (Monad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 numberLine :: Monad m => Conduit ByteString m ByteString
      at exp.hs:(8,1)-(11,30)
    Possible fix:
      add (Num [ByteString]) to the context of
        the type signature for
          numberLine :: Monad m => Conduit ByteString m ByteString
      or add an instance declaration for (Num [ByteString])
    In the first argument of `conduitState', namely `0'
    In the expression: conduitState 0 push close
    In an equation for `numberLine':
        numberLine
          = conduitState 0 push close
          where
              push lno input
                = return
                  $ StateProducing (lno + 1) [pack (show lno ++ unpack input)]
              close state = return state
```

How can this be done using conduits? I want to read lines from a file and append a line number to each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
close state = return state
```

Herein lies the type error. Your `close` function should have type `(state -> m [output])` (as per [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/conduit/0.4.2/doc/html/Data-Conduit.html#v%3aconduitState)). In your case `state = Int` (you may want to add type annotations to make sure it selects `Int`) and `output = BS.ByteString`, so probably just return the empty list, since at the point of closing the conduit, you haven't really saved any `ByteString`s to produce or anything like that.

```
close _ = return []
```

Especially note from the docs for that argument:

> The state need not be returned, since it will not be used again

Comment: Thank you! I should have paid more attention to the types.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it can be done. I prefer to use the helper functions in `Data.Conduit.List` and also avoid `Data.ByteString.Char8` if at all possible. I'm assuming your file is UTF-8 encoded.

```
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary as CB
import Data.Conduit.List as Cl
import Data.Conduit.Text as Ct
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Data.Text as T

numberLine :: Monad m => Conduit Text m Text
numberLine = Cl.concatMapAccum step 0 where
  format input lno = T.pack (show lno) <> T.pack " " <> input <> T.pack "\n"
  step input lno = (lno+1, [format input lno])

main :: IO ()
main =
  runResourceT
     $ CB.sourceFile "wp.txt"
    $$ Ct.decode Ct.utf8
    =$ Ct.lines
    =$ numberLine
    =$ Ct.encode Ct.utf8
    =$ CB.sinkFile "test.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I would like to know whats wrong with my code. The idea to use UTF8 is useful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with [pipes 3.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-3.0.0), though it does use string instead of ByteString. The main advantage in my mind is being able to use the normal state monad methods get and put. Another benefit is that the starting line number is not hidden in the addLineNumber(numberLine) so it is easier to start at any given line number.

```
import System.IO
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Control.Proxy
import qualified Control.Proxy.Trans.State as S

addLineNumber r = forever $ do
    n <- S.get
    line <- request r -- request line from file
    respond $ show n <> " " <> line
    S.put (n + 1) -- increments line counter

main = 
    withFile "wp.txt" ReadMode    $ \fin  ->
    withFile "test.txt" WriteMode $ \fout ->
    runProxy $ S.execStateK 1 -- start at line number at 1
             $ hGetLineS fin >-> addLineNumber >-> hPutStrLnD fout
```

Find out how to do more fine grained resource management at the announce [blog post of pipes-safe.](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/01/pipes-safe-10-resource-management-and.html).